# Unable to setup SQLServer connection in JetBrains DataGrip 2020.1.4

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I have installed the latest version of JetBrains' DataGrip.

```
DataGrip 2020.1.4
Build #DB-201.7846.70, built on May 29, 2020
Licensed to XXX

Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b765.53 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 12
```

And when I try to setup a SQL connection. It throws an error, and all the error says is `.` a full stop.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:**
The fix is available in [DataGrip 2020.1.5](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/download/).

It's a known issue.

Follow instructions in our blog post [Workaround for sql server authentication issue on windows](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2020/06/01/workaround-for-sql-server-authentication-issue-on-windows/).

Fix will be available in the nearest DataGrip version and also available in DataGrip 2020.2 EAP 1.